# Linux GCC Compiler creating a non-valid executable

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm experiencing the following issue:

I'm trying to create an executable from a C source file. I am using GCC compiler with the following command:

```
gcc vuln.c -o vuln
```

but the newly created file (vuln) is not in a valid format or is not executable. I'm getting the following error while trying to execute "vuln"

```
./vuln:
Usage Error:
```

Screenshots :

- Terminal[image]
- Folder containing vuln.c and vuln[image]

Comment: You need to add way more info. Source code first and foremost. And error message for running the executable.

Comment: How do you know that `vuln` is not a proper executable?  How do you know that the `Usage error:` message that you're getting isn't coming from the `vuln` executable?

Comment: I think your code uses some sort CLI framework and your program expects some parameters. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Allright, my bad. It seems it is a proper executable and I did not provide arguments when executing './vuln'. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that vuln was a proper executable and I did not provide any arguments when calling `./vuln`. That's why I was getting `Usage Error:`